# How to specify start time of continuous query in InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb

The following data is from the [InfluxDB documentation about continuous queries](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/continuous_queries/):

```
name: bus_data
--------------
time                   passengers   complaints
2016-08-28T07:00:00Z   5            9
2016-08-28T07:15:00Z   8            9
2016-08-28T07:30:00Z   8            9
2016-08-28T07:45:00Z   7            9
2016-08-28T08:00:00Z   8            9
2016-08-28T08:15:00Z   15           7
2016-08-28T08:30:00Z   15           7
2016-08-28T08:45:00Z   17           7
2016-08-28T09:00:00Z   20           7
```

In this example the data is grouped by 15 minutes and starts from `2016-08-28T07:00:00Z`. How do I specify when a continuous query should start running? I do not want to end up with time stamps like `2016-08-28T07:03:17Z` but I'd rather have a 'clean' start time like in the example.